# Using @BASENAME@ with install_dir of custom_target() in Meson

Tags: meson-build

`@BASENAME@` does not appear to work in the `install_dir:` parameter of the [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) [`custom_target()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target) function.

```py
protoc = find_program('protoc')

protobuf_sources= [
'apples.proto',
'oranges.proto',
'pears.proto'
]

protobuf_generated_go = []
foreach protobuf_definition : protobuf_sources

protobuf_generated_go += custom_target('go_' + protobuf_definition,
       command: [protoc, '--proto_path=@CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@', '--go_out=paths=source_relative:@OUTDIR@', '@INPUT@'],
       input: protobuf_definition,
       output: '@BASENAME@.pb.go',
       install: true,
       install_dir: 'share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/@BASENAME@/'
)

endforeach
```

I need the generated files to end up in at directory based on the basename of the input file:

```
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/apples/apples.pb.go
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/oranges/oranges.pb.go
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/pears/pears.pb.go
```

If I use `@BASENAME@` in `install_dir:` to try and create the directory needed, it does not expand, and instead just creates a literal '`@BASENAME@`' directory.

```
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/@BASENAME@/apples.pb.go
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/@BASENAME@/oranges.pb.go
share/gocode/src/github.com/foo/bar/protobuf/go/@BASENAME@/pears.pb.go
```

How can the required installed directory location based on the basename be achieved?
(just 3 files in the above example, I actually have 30+ files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks as there is no support for placeholders like BASENAME for install_dir parameter since this feature aims at file names not directories. But you can process iterator that is string in a loop:

```
foreach protobuf_definition : protobuf_sources
       ...

       install_dir: '.../go/@0@'.format(protobuf_definition.split('.')[0]) 

endforeach
```